# Messiah's tribal pedigree, and the Diaspora

Tags: messiah, genealogy, golus-exile, shevatim-12-tribes

How will the Messiah prove he is from the tribe of Judah if the diaspora has obliterated tribal delineation?

Comment: This question is either really good or really trivial. Providing a reason to think your antecedent is true would do much to ensure the question as a whole falls in the former category.

Comment: What if, say, he had a really big family tree? http://www.davidicdynasty.org/images/Dayan_tree.gif

Comment: Sourcing your implied assumption that he needs to be from Judah would boost your question's value. (That's in addition to, and IMO even more crucial than, @DoubleAA's request that you source your antecedent, that the diaspora has obliterated tribal delineation.)

Comment: http://img2.tapuz.co.il/forums/71682095.pdf

Answer (score -1):

The Messiah will prove his Davidic lineage through his fulfillment of the unique accomplishments of the Messiah (see a listing of such accomplishments in Mishneh Torah [Laws of Kings 11:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e511.htm#4)). His lineage is known to the one who selected him, God. Genealogical paperwork is neither a necessary nor sufficient condition for being Messiah.

http://teshuvashaminim.blogspot.com/2012/09/genealogical-records-these-sought-their.html

Comment: While this is possible, the blog post cited just seems to speculate it, not justify it with a traditional source. How do we know this is accurate?

Comment: 1. No source is needed to refute an unsourced/hypothetical requirement. 2. The answer cites traditional sources on what is required to identify the Messiah, and records are not included. 3. The answer demonstrates that such a "requirement" is not necessary and this is elaborated upon in the link.

Comment: 1. You are right, but it's your word versus his, and I don't think yours is so obviously right. 2. The answer only cites ways of identifying if a king from the House of David is the Messiah, not if he is from the House of David. 3. The answer demonstrates no such thing (this point and it's refutation are the same as point 2...)