# Is the line of David known/documented?

Tags: abraham, genealogy

Bear in mind, I have a background in Christianity, so my superficial knowledge of Judaism is at best base on the old testament. In the old testament David is told his line will result in the Messiah.

I know in Judaism it's believed that the messiah hasn't arrived yet; and was curious of there were any contemporary or historical attempts to track the line of David in efforts to watch for the messiah. Obviously, if such knowledge were lost that would hardly stop the messiah from being born, but I was curious if it exist.

Comment: First of all, Abraham is never told by G-d that his line will produce the Messiah. This is only common sense; the Messiah is to be Jewish, descended from David and Solomon, who is in turn a descendant of Abraham. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25581/11486) for more. (It's from [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857/11486), which isn't totally relevant to your question as a whole, but it does address the requirements for the Jewish Messiah.)

Comment: Famously the Syrian Jewish community won't accept converts/marry converts because they have a strong tradition of being direct descendants of King David.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95482/on-the-day-when-the-mashiach-is-finally-revealed-how-are-we-supposed-to-determi https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31948/messiahs-tribal-pedigree-and-the-diaspora https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59523/how-will-we-know-the-moshiach-when-he-arrives https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47696/who-are-the-descendants-of-king-david-today